# How do I inhibit shortcuts for Virtual Machines

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, virtualization, virt-manager

When I launched virt-manager in Ubuntu under GNOME I was presented with a dialogue:

```
Virtual Machine Manager wants to inhibit shortcuts.
You can restore shortcuts by pressing Super+Escape. 

Deny? Allow?
```

I accidentally chose `Deny`. How do I get this dialogue to reappear so I can chose the option I intended `Allow`? I searched the settings and couldn't find any type of toggle.

I want to inhibit shortcuts for Virtual Machine manager, that way when I'm in a guest the keyboard shortcut I press (eg `Super`) is input to the guest, not the host. By mistakenly choosing `Deny` I've forced all shortcuts to be fed to the host.

Comment: 'You can restore shortcuts by pressing Super+Escape.' - I assume you tried that and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't get the dialogue back, but in essence it chooses the `Allow` option originally mentioned:

```
flatpak permission-set gnome shortcuts-inhibitor virt-manager.desktop GRANTED
flatpak permission-set gnome shortcuts-inhibitor virt-viewer.desktop GRANTED
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dialog back by removing the currently saved value.

1. Install [d-spy](https://apps.gnome.org/Dspy)
2. On the left bar -

   1. Choose **Session** bus
   2. Select `org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore`
3. On the main window (right side), expand the entries in this order -

   - /org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore
   - **Interfaces** → org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore
4. [At this point, your d-spy window should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpZOJ.png)
5. Click on **Methods** → DeletePermission
   A panel should open up from the bottom of the window
6. In the *Parameters* text field of the panel, paste the following text -

   ```
   ('gnome','shortcuts-inhibitor', 'virt-manager.desktop')
   ```

   And press the **Execute** button
7. Repeat previous step, but with this text instead -

   ```
   ('gnome','shortcuts-inhibitor', 'virt-viewer.desktop')
   ```

Now, when you try running virt-manager again, it should prompt for the same dialogue again.